# How can I open the built-in browser in Visual Studio without opening a link?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left mouse button on a link in Visual Studio, the built-in browser opens. Is it possible to open the built-in browser in Visual Studio *without* opening a link?

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to open browser without clicking any link in editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either open the 'View' menu, select 'Other Windows' and choose 'Web Browser', or use the shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>).

[image]